# WPF TreeView and Disabled Item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF `TreeView` with some of the items disabled - `IsEnabled = false`.

When I click on the disabled item, the parent item gets selected (I don't like this).
I want to stay on the current item when some disabled item is clicked.
Is this possible and how?

Comment: Maybe you can bind `IsHitTestVisible` to `IsEnabled`.

Comment: Bind IsFocusable to IsEnabled.

Comment: LPL, write the answer and I will accept, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to `IsEnabled`. Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Please correct me if this sample is wrong. I have no TreeView at hand to validate the sample code. Thanks.

Comment: I have done it in the code - put the same value as in IsEnabled and I think that in XAML would be like you wrote.