# WPF MVVM TreeView: prevent selection of a parent node when clicking on the disabled node

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, wpf-controls, multi-select

I'm trying to implement a custom `TreeView` with multiselect. For my reasons I can't use existing solutions.

My problem is: I have a `TreeViewItem` some child items of which are disabled. And sometimes when I click on a enabled node and then on disabled node the parent node become selected.

I 'd like to get rid of this default selection behaviour, because all items in my treeview have a databinded property `IsSelected` which I set when I actually click on the item and I don't want treeview to select some items by yourself!

**Update:** I need to handle clicks on disabled items, so set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` is not a solution for me.

Any help and ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF TreeView and Disabled Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105104/wpf-treeview-and-disabled-item)

Comment: I saw this question, but I actually want to handle click on the disabled item, I only don't want this weird behaviour :(

Answer (score 1):

Try the examples from :

Multi Selection TreeView in WPF:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55569/Multi-selection-TreeView-in-WPF-the-easy-way

and

http://www.codingtavern.com/2010/01/multi-selection-treeview-in-wpf-easy.html

Comment: This tree works good exept for the moment when I click on a disabled item... Anyway maybe it may help!